# Count occurrences of factors, comma separated, AND conditional? in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I'm trying to do some complex calculations and part of the code requires that I parse a comma separated entry and count the number of values that are more than 0.

Example input data:

```
a <- c(0,0,3,0)
b <- c(4,4,0,1)
c <- c("3,4,3", "2,1", 0, "5,8")
x <- data.frame(a, b, c)

x

  a b     c
1 0 4 3,4,3
2 0 4   2,1
3 3 0     0
4 0 1   5,8
```

The column that I need to parse, `c` is factors and all other columns are numeric. The number of values comma separated will vary, in this example it varies from 0 to 3.
**The desired output would look like this**:

```
x$c_occur <- c(3, 2, 0, 2)
x

  a b     c c_occur
1 0 4 3,4,3       3
2 0 4   2,1       2
3 3 0     0       0
4 0 1   5,8       2
```

Where `c_occur` lists the number of occurrences > 0 in the c column.

I was thinking something like this would work... but I can't figure it out.

```
library(dplyr
 x_desired <- x %>%
   mutate(c_occur = count(strsplit(c, ","), > 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
x %>%
    mutate(c_occur = str_count(c, '[1-9]\\d*'))
#  a b     c c_occur
#1 0 4 3,4,3       3
#2 0 4   2,1       2
#3 3 0     0       0
#4 0 1   5,8       2
```

---

After splitting the 'c', we can get the count by `sum`ming the logical vector after looping over the `list` output from `strsplit`

```
library(purrr)    
x %>%
   mutate(c_occur =  map_int(strsplit(as.character(c), ","),
       ~ sum(as.integer(.x) > 0)))
# a b     c c_occur
#1 0 4 3,4,3       3
#2 0 4   2,1       2
#3 3 0     0       0
#4 0 1   5,8       2
```

---

Or we can separate the rows with `separate_rows` and do a `group_by` `summarise`

```
library(tidyr)    
x %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
     separate_rows(c, convert = TRUE) %>%
     group_by(rn) %>%
     summarise(c_occur = sum(c >0)) %>%
     select(-rn) %>% 
     bind_cols(x, .)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      a     b c     c_occur
#  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   <int>
#1     0     4 3,4,3       3
#2     0     4 2,1         2
#3     3     0 0           0
#4     0     1 5,8         2
```

Comment: If input variables are greater than 9, "[1-9]" doesn't work, is there a way around this?

Comment: The map_int() with purrr library worked great. thanks!

Comment: @shu251 can you change that pattern to `'[1-9]\\d*'`